# I want to access a camera stream from a local IP address. I can access that stream IP in chrome browser, but when I try in my flutter web it not works

Tags: flutter, web, video, camera, ip

I've tried several packages to access videos such as videoplayer and chewie but still not able to. I'm using a web camera connected to a raspberry pi, and I want to access it from my laptop's flutter web.